# TypeError: hash must be unicode or bytes, not None

Tags: python, unicode, hash, flask, typeerror

I am working on Flask project works with mongoengine. Register code  hashed to password with **passlib.hash** when user registered. When I try to read password in login authentication I've got this error.

**TypeError: hash must be unicode or bytes, not None**

[image]

**Traceback:**

```
TypeError
TypeError: hash must be unicode or bytes, not appname.models.User

Traceback (most recent call last)

File "/*/**/***/***/appname/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

File "/*/**/***/***/appname/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))

File "/*/**/***/***/appname/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "/*/**/***/***/appname/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()

File "/*/**/***/***/appname/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)

File "/*/**/***/***/appname/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)

File "/*/**/***/***/appname/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()

File "/*/**/***/***/appname/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)

File "/*/**/***/***/appname/views.py", line 207, in login
if sha256_crypt.verify(u''+ passW,user):

File "/*/**/***/***/appname/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/passlib/utils/handlers.py", line 567, in verify
self = cls.from_string(hash, **context)

File "/*/**/***/***/appname/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/passlib/handlers/sha2_crypt.py", line 285, in from_string
hash = to_unicode(hash, "ascii", "hash")

File "/*/**/***/***/appname/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/passlib/utils/__init__.py", line 617, in to_unicode
raise ExpectedStringError(source, param)

TypeError: hash must be unicode or bytes, not appname.models.User
The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI application. You can now look at the traceback which led to the error.

To switch between the interactive traceback and the plaintext one, you can click on the "Traceback" headline. From the text traceback you can also create a paste of it. For code execution mouse-over the frame you want to debug and click on the console icon on the right side.

You can execute arbitrary Python code in the stack frames and there are some extra helpers available for introspection:

dump() shows all variables in the frame
dump(obj) dumps all that's known about the object
```

Here is my **views.py** codes:

```
@app.route("/login", methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        flash("You're already registered", "info")
        return redirect(url_for('profile')+('/'+current_user.slug))

    form = LoginForm()
    passW = form.password.data

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm()

        if form.validate_on_submit():
            user = User.objects(email=form.email.data, password=str(passW)).first()
            if sha256_crypt.verify(passW, user):
                login_user(user, form.remember_me.data)
                slug = slugify(user.name)

                flash('We are glad you came {}.'.format(user.name),'success')
                return redirect(request.args.get('next') or url_for('profile', slug=slug))

            else:
                flash('Wrong username or password.','danger')
                return render_template("login.html", form=form, title="Cp-Login")
    return render_template("login.html", form=form, title="Cp-Login")
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: paste your complete traceback into your question, and format it as code {}

Comment: I added the things you asked. Thanks.

Comment: After you change your code or request, your error message is now TypeError: hash must be unicode or bytes, not appname.models.User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is here:

```
user = User.objects(email=form.email.data, password=str(passW)).first()
```

If your database can't find any match user,  user will be none. So you'd better use if else to tell if the user exist first.

#### EDIT

From the doc in Passlib,

```
>>> # import the hash algorithm
>>> from passlib.hash import sha256_crypt

>>> # generate new salt, and hash a password
>>> hash = sha256_crypt.encrypt("toomanysecrets")
>>> hash
'$5$rounds=80000$zvpXD3gCkrt7tw.1$QqeTSolNHEfgryc5oMgiq1o8qCEAcmye3FoMSuvgToC'

>>> # verifying the password
>>> sha256_crypt.verify("toomanysecrets", hash)
True
>>> sha256_crypt.verify("joshua", hash)
False
```

Your code

```
if sha256_crypt.verify(passW, user):
```

should be

```
if sha256_crypt.verify(passW, user.password):
```

if you store user's password use Passlib. But usually you should use django build-in [authenticating](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#authenticating-users) to do something like this.

Comment: Thanks, it helped. Also I had to do some changes. I am answering my question now with your help. :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Just as @aison said above I had to change objects variable with the objects field variable as user.password

```
if sha256_crypt.verify(passW, user.password):
```

Also needed to change model queryset itself. I removed the password field in the query, beacuse the password already verifying sha256_crypt statement after the form validation above

**before modifying**

```
user = User.objects(email=form.email.data, password=str(passW)).first()
```

**after modifying**

```
user = User.objects(email=form.email.data).first()
```

Hash verify statement that @aison suggested do the rest

```
if sha256_crypt.verify(passW, user.password):
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case (fastAPI) i just make mistake when declare types of class in schemas.py
should be looks like
password: str
instead
password = str

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33087541)